# How can I generate pink noise using Mathematica?

Tags: random, code-request, signal-processing

I need a time series of pink noise. How can I generate pink noise using Mathematica?

Comment: if you have v11 look at `AudioGenerator`

Comment: @george2079 That generates audio, is it possible to extract the time series?

Comment: @C.E. I don't have v11,  just found it in the online docs.

Comment: Never heard of pink noise. Could you provide some links so we know exactly what definition you are using? Also, show us what you tried. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @ivbc Thanks. Look here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise
Now I am trying to use entropy to analysis the complexity of white noise and pink noise(1/f).These pink-like noises occur widely in nature. First, I need generating a time series of pink noise.

Comment: @ivbc I just find it: "The 1/f noise is generated as follows: we start with uniformly distributed white noise, calculate the fast Fourier transform (FFT), and after imposing a 1/f distribution on the power spectrum, we calculate the inverse FFT. "

Comment: @Julian, nice to learn one more thing! Try to add that link to you question, so it gets more informative and gets more up votes too. ;)

Comment: some discussion of first principles generation here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16880/138814  . It seems straightforward to implement using `WhiteNoiseProcess`  though I don't have confidence that I understand it well enough to post as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

The approach below is still somewhat brute-force, but it was greatly improved by Carl Woll's suggestion to look into AudioData, which was the link I was missing here.

It works to generate a pink noise set using the output of `AudioGenerator`. you should be able to adapt the code to arbitrary sampling frequency and data length:

```
audio = AudioGenerator["Pink"]

data = Transpose@{
    Range[0, 1 - 1/44100, 1/44100.], 
    AudioData[audio]
  };

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For data extraction, look at [`AudioData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioData)

Comment: @MacroB  Thanks a lot. It seems work well.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you! I was looking for that function exactly, and somehow I overlooked the link right there at the bottom of the documentation page for `Audio` :-( Is there a way to extract the timing information as well, or is that simply recreated based on sampling frequency?

Comment: @Julian You're welcome. I have modified the code to use `AudioData`, which is definitely more elegant, thanks  to Carl's suggestion. That should look a little better and probably be faster.

Comment: For sample rate, use [`AudioSampleRate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioSampleRate)

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer now, but probably using `FARIMAprocess` is the best approach.