# generating 1/f noise

Tags: fourier-analysis

the spectrum of noise δε(t) is S(ω)=<|δε(ω)|²>, where δε(ω) is a Fourier coef. of δε(t). And the relationship between the variance σ² of a zero-mean δε(t) and the spectrum is

[image]……(I),

where ωl（ωh）is the low(high) cutoff of ω.

I **want to generating 1/f noise series δε(t)**, whose variance is σ² and sepctrum is A/ω.
**Method** :

Calculating A according to formula (I).

And generate discrete white noise series ft, which has Fourier components fω and fω distributing with variance A.

Then multiply each Fourier components fω with 1/Sqrt[ω] and do an InverseFourier of the new Fourier components to get δε(t).

Therefore the spectrum of δε(t) is S(ω)=<|fω/Sqrt[ω]|²>=A/ω.

What's wrong with the following code that don't give me the right variance of δε(t)?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; \[Sigma] = 0.25*2*Pi; \[Omega]l = 0.0001*2*Pi; \[Omega]h = 20*2*Pi; A = x /. Solve[Integrate[x/(2*Pi*\[Omega]), {\[Omega], 0.0001*2*Pi, 20*2*Pi}] == \[Sigma]^2, x][[1]]; f\[Omega] = Fourier[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[A]], 200000]]; f\[Omega]2 = f\[Omega][[2 ;; 200000]]*Table[1/Sqrt[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0.0001*2*Pi, (20 - 0.0001)*2*Pi, 
  0.0001*2*Pi}]; f\[Omega]2 = Join[f\[Omega]2[[1 ;; 100000]], Reverse[Conjugate[f\[Omega]2[[1 ;; 100000 - 1]]]]]; PrependTo[f\[Omega]2, 0]; \[Delta]\[Epsilon] = InverseFourier[f\[Omega]2]; Variance[\[Delta]\[Epsilon]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have got the issues with `Fourier` well under control. However, I would do it by having a defined modulus and a random phase. How about

```
nn = 400000; (* Number of spectral points *)
finc = 0.0001; (* Frequency increment *)
mod = Table[1/f, {f, finc, nn/2 finc, finc}];
ph = Join[RandomReal[{-π, π}, nn/2 - 1], {0}];
s1 = mod E^(I ph);
s2 = Join[{0}, s1, Reverse[Conjugate[s1[[1 ;; -2]]]]];
ms = s2 . Conjugate[s2]; (* Total squared value *)
ListLogLogPlot[Abs[s2[[1 ;; nn/2]]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Now we work out the `InverseFourier` to get a time history with particular `FourierParameters`. I also make the mean square value equal to 1.0.

```
th = 1/Sqrt[ms] InverseFourier[s2, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
ListLinePlot[th[[1 ;; 100000]]]
```

[image]

The mean square value is what we want

```
1/nn th . th

(* 1. + 2.42086*10^-16 I *)
```

Perhaps I should have removed the small imaginary part due to numerical noise.

Is this along the lines of what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your fast and elaborate answer. But sorry for my misleading using of  "spectrum", which I used does not mean the frequency domain of the noise series but the noise power density. And I think the variance , according to formula (I), is \[Sigma]^2 = (0.25*2*Pi)^2.

Comment: I have given how you can calculate one interval of the time history. To generate longer time histories then you can repeat and join the outputs together.  The power spectrum is the result of averaging many  intervals. It will have the spectrum you desire.

Comment: I don't understand how can it be possible to meet my spectrum when the time history doesn't depend on the noise strength Sqrt[A].

Comment: The noise strength is just a factor you use to scale the time history (or spectrum). Multiply the time history by 2 and your mean square values goes up by 4.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your answer and patience @Hugh ! Could you please recommend a textbook about this, I literally know nothing about noise analysis.

Comment: I hesitate to recommend a textbook there are many. Some are very mathematical  others very practical.  You will have to search the areas of signal processing and spectral analysis.  There is also  a stack exchange site for [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Shouldn't mod = Table[1/f, {f, finc, nn/2 finc, finc}]; be           
        mod = Table[Sqrt[1/f], {f, finc, nn/2 finc, finc}];?

Comment: Also, look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/how-can-i-generate-pink-noise-using-mathematica, specifically, look at the noises choices for https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioGenerator.html

Comment: @Moo That could also be a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Depends what you want. Do you want the modulus squared to go as 1/f or the modulus to go as 1/f?  If you want the power spectrum (modulus squared) to go as 1/f then you do want Sqrt[1/f] for the modulus.

Comment: @Hugh Yep, I want the power spectrum to go as 1/f. Thanks again.